# Permission denied for compiling mysql in CDT eclipse

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse, ubuntu, permission-denied

I have a remote machine which I connected it by echoVNC and I access by vnc user & password. I installed eclipse CDT and I also installed mysql under the vnc user. I wrote a small program which should use mysql API. I've given it like this.

1. Under properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC Compiler->Includes added `var/lib/mysql`, `/usr/lib64/mysql` and `/usr/include/mysql`
2. Under properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC Compiler->Miscellaneous `-c -fmessage-length=0 $(mysql_config --cflags)`
3. Under properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC Linker->Libraries->Libraries`(-I) $(mysql_config --libs)`
4. Under properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC Linker->Libraries->Library search path(`-L`) added `/usr/include`, `var/lib/mysql`, `/usr/lib64/mysql` and `/usr/include/mysql`
5. Under properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->GCC Linker->Miscellaneous `-pthread -lm -lrt`

But when I compile the program the error is:

> cc1plus: fatal error: /var/lib/mysql/stdc-predef.h: Permission denied

Please advise how I should handle the permission of mysql so it will be relevant to the program.

Comment: wouldn't this be similar to my logging in as an o/s user lacking permissions, going to o/s root, and doing a `find` cmd ? If so, the user needs a bump up of rights in a directory or file via `chmod` ... but this really isn't a programming question.

Comment: This issue has been solved - Thanks !